# Under what general conditions can one sue for money from an organization or person?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, civil-claims

Under what general conditions can one sue for money from an organization or person?

Are there any resources out there that can easily summarize when one can sue?

I see that many people sue for settlement or money for many different reasons.

Comment: @DaleM's answer is a appropriate for the vagueness of the question which I probably would have voted to close. "Are there any resources out there that can easily summarize when one can sue?" No. Lawyers spend three years in law school learning that (although most of the main ones are covered in the first year of law school).

Answer (score 3):

### When you have standing, a cause of action, and have suffered loss

[Standing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standing_(law)) means you have sufficient connection to the harm that the law will recognize your injury.

A [cause of action](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cause_of_action) is the legal right you claim was transgressed.

Broadly, there needs to be a [remedy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_remedy) that lies within the jurisdiction of the court to grant. Monetary remedies are called [damages](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damages) and for most causes of action you need to prove your loss although some have statutory damages and others allow nominal damages.